# How can i disable Vaadin table lazy loading

Tags: java, lazy-loading, vaadin, vaadin7

I want to load a grid all of the items, but vaadin grid loads items lazily. I want to use some of the browser capabilities, but i cant show all of the items in a grid.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the [pageLength](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html#setPageLength%28int%29) to 0. That should disable paging. Maybe setting the pageLength to the number of elements could also help.

I had similar and more requirements and wrote my own add-on called [PMTable](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/pmtable)
It does not use paging, but some features do not exist and some are not tested.