# Getting size of table less than aria-rowcount

Tags: java

I am getting table row count but row count isn't correct. Or at least it is not what is expected.
I need to get the same amount of rows as Developer Tools's info shows in tag table: "table role="grid" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-rowcount="93"".

Code:

method getTable:

```
public Table getTable(String table) {
        return new Table(driver, driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='" + table + "']//tbody")));
    }
```

method getRowCount:

```
public int getRowCount() {
    return tableContent.findElements(By.tagName("tr")).size();
}
```

and in the test i call it like this:

```
getTable("MyTable").getRowCount();
```

and the result is for example 29. But in Developers Tools i see <table role="grid" aria-multiselectable="false" **aria-rowcount="93"**>

The question is, how to get this whole table, that has 93 rows in it? How to get this aria table?
I already tried so many xpath paths, so i just can't figure it out. Maybe anyone already met something like this?

Maybe it could be case like this: [Scrapping Dynamic Table Using Selenium WebDriver Wait Returning Truncated Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70726960/scrapping-dynamic-table-using-selenium-webdriver-wait-returning-truncated-data-f)
But in my case **there are no pagination visible**. All i have in front of my eyes is a big table with more than 29 rows definitely.

I apologize again cause i cannot share the project and i really can't find any alike code examples on which you can test the code, but could be really useful to get at least some tips from you.

Comment: There is no `id` in your given code chunk: `<table role="grid" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-rowcount="93">`. So how can you find a table with id `MyTable` , like you are doing here: `getTable("MyTable")`

I am sorry, I guess nobody can help without relevant code and relevant data(in this case, your html file sample)

Comment: aria-table is within div with classname 'v-grid v-widget v-has-width v-has-height' and that div has an ID which i enter into getTable method. and i suppose this table is not an actual table but only a grid, so this grid displays only 29 rows which is exactly what is on a screen at the moment. but how to get whole table i just can\t figure that out.

Comment: Yeah, but we cannot guess without html file. Maybe other rows are not in `tr` tags, or maybe in a different div/table altogether. You'll have to share html file, Maybe you can remove sensitive data from it, or generate it using dummy data

Comment: i wish i could share html, but in the body of it it is really a mess like wrapped text, don't have a time to make it prettier. maybe image would help somehow https://postimg.cc/qhDYBNqg

Comment: Are the rows lazy loaded on the fly, as you scroll down?

Comment: Seems so, all i see in DOM if i scroll, that Y parameter in translate3d(x,y,z) is changing its value.

Comment: i suppose that this tip might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465671/how-can-i-disable-vaadin-table-lazy-loading?rq=1 to set pageLength, but i don't understand how to apply that to my test. has anyone such experience?

Comment: How does it work from a user perspective? I mean does user have to scroll down to load more records, or are there any "load more" links? User actions can be simulated in good web clients like Selenium

Comment: appreciate attention. from user perspective it is just a big table so that you have to scroll down to see more rows and there is no pages or "load more" options.

Comment: seems noone has encountered this.. sad